# Regex Remove some text

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I have a regex and `replace()` to replace some CSS. I have some CSS classes in a variable.

```
var BodyContent = "body{background:red;width:450;}";
BodyContent = BodyContent.replace(/background:\s*([^;]+)/, "");

alert(BodyContent); // returns "body{;width:450;}";
```

But it doesn't remove the `;`after `background`.

The expected result is:

```
body{width:450;}
```

**NOTE:** All these are text and not from a web page. Please do not suggest using DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
BodyContent = BodyContent.replace(/background:\s*([^;]+);/ ,"");
```

You missed a `;` at the end of the regex.